# Thermal sensor location and adhesive

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature, desktop-computer

I bought a DIY computer over Christmas (I bought all the parts and hooked it together myself). The mid-tower case I got ([this one](http://www.nzxt.com/product/detail/109-guardian-921-rb-case.html), in blue) has three thermal sensors that need to be attached at certain locations or to certain components. The problem is, aside from the labels on the sensors, there is zero documentation on where precisely these sensors go. The three sensors are:

- CPU
- SYS (system, I assume)
- HDD

Looking online, I found where the HDD sensor should be attached. For the CPU, it sounds like there really is no good place to attach it (you can't attach it to CPU directly) and for the system, the best answer I got was "where ever you want to monitor the temperature in your case". Since I'm not a h/w expert, I really don't know where to place it.

Secondly, even if I did know where to put the other two sensors, I don't know what kind of adhesive to use. I've seen some photos of one attached with some sort of tape, but I don't know what kind of tape it is. I've also heard mention of some sort of glue, but once again, I don't know what kind.

Does anyone know where to attach these sensors, or, at the very least, what type of adhesive to use?

Comment: Where do these sensors wires go to exactly?  They seem useless without a controller.  The CPU will be able to report its temperature even without that sensor.  The SYS sensor indicates the temperature of the case which is sort of pointless.

Comment: The sensors go to external displays on the case. The case has three windows which show the temp of the three (CPU, SYS and HDD).